# Do I always have to include virtual properties when saving data in EF?

Tags: entity-framework

My user looks like this:

```
public class User 
{
    public User() 
    {
        Subscribers = new List<SubscriberNumber>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual BusinessNumber BusinessNumber { get; set; }
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    public int SubscriberCount { get; set; }

    public List<SubscriberNumber> Subscribers { get; set; }
}
```

The following call fails due to some undisclosed EntityValidationError:

```
var user = db.Users.First(s => s.Username == username);
user.BusinessName = "test";
db.SaveChanges();
```

But either opening up `user.BusinessNumber` in VS or using the following:

```
var user = db.Users.Include(s => s.BusinessNumber).First(s => s.Username == username);
```

gets `SaveChanges()` to work.  Do I always have to include virtual properties when I'm updating my Users?  This seems cumbersome...

Comment: You set `BusinessNumber` as `[Required]` so always you have to set a value for it.

Answer (score 0):

The virtual on the properties allows EF to build a proxy. It is not essential to use virtual on regular properties for EF to read and write data. However Virtual is required on the Navigation properties.
By Default `Context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;`
EF will trigger validation on `SaveChanges()`.

So in teh example where the Navigation property is Required (why?) The you must first populate it in the context and POCO. Placing the `[required]` on the foreign key property rather than the navigation property would be more common.

```
public class User 
{
public User() 
{
    Subscribers = new List<SubscriberNumber>();
}

[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int UserId { get; set; }
public string Username { get; set; }

[Required]
public virtual int BusinessId {get;set;};   // make the foreign key to BusinessNumber required if necessary

[ForeignKey("BusinessId")]
public virtual BusinessNumber BusinessNumber { get; set; }  // this is a nav prop, since it isnt a simple base type

public string BusinessName { get; set; }
public int SubscriberCount { get; set; }

public List<SubscriberNumber> Subscribers { get; set; }
}
```